# How to convert java Map to scala Map of type LinkedHashMap[String,ArrayList[String]]?

Tags: scala

from Java API I get

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[String]]
```

which I then need to pass as a parameter to a scala program

```
val rmap = Foo.baz(parameter)
```

This parameter is of scala type:

```
Map[String,List[String]]
```

So how can I easily convert

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[String]]
```

to

```
Map[String,List[String]]
```

I tried using import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ but in my case this does not work (or at least thats what I guess) because the scala code is in template function and I can only place import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ inside the function.
the template function is like:

```
def someFunc(param: java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[String]]) = {
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val rmap = Foo.baz(param) // param is of scala type Map[String,List[String]]
.......
```

Now scala is not auto converting java type to scala type.

This is the compiler error I get:
Error raised is : type mismatch; found : java.util.LinkedHashMap[String,java.util.ArrayList[String]] required: Map[String,List[String]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got two problems: Map and List in scala are different from the java versions.

scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap creates a mutable map, so using the mutable map, the following works:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

val f = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, java.util.ArrayList[String]]
var g: Map[String, java.util.ArrayList[String]] = f
```

The ArrayList is a bit harder. The following works:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

val a = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
var b: Buffer[String] = a
```

But if we try

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

val f = new java.util.LinkedHashMap[String, java.util.ArrayList[String]]
var g: Map[String, Buffer[String]] = f
```

this doesn't work. Your best option is to define an explicit implicit conversion yourself for this.

Comment: "an explicit implicit conversion".  <3 Scala.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Just import `scala.collection.JavaConversions` and you should be set :)
It performs conversions from Scala collections to Java collections and vice-versa.

If it doesn't work smoothly, try:

```
val m: Map[String,List[String]] = javaMap
```

You might also need to convert each one of the lists inside the map:

```
m.map {
  l => val sl: List[String] = l
  sl
}
```

Comment: That's not correct; you need to `import collection.JavaConversions._`.

Comment: that is true. import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ than all collections are converted implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala.collection.JavaConversions.mapAsScalaMap
```

or something similar in the JavaConversions Object

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
val rmap = Foo.baz(parameter.asScala.toMap.mapValues(v => v.asScala.toList))
```

Import below in your code -

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```