# Odd typing bug in Scala

Tags: scala, types

Take a look at this:

```
scala> class Container(val rows: Iterable[Iterable[Option[Any]]]) {} 
defined class Container

scala> val row1 = Array(Some("test"),Some(1234))
row1: Array[Some[Any]] = Array(Some(test), Some(1234))

scala> val row2 = Array(Some("test2"), Some(12345))
row2: Array[Some[Any]] = Array(Some(test2), Some(12345))

scala> val listtest = List(row1, row2)
listtest: List[Array[Some[Any]]] = List(Array(Some(test), Some(1234)), Array(Some(test2), Some(12345)))

scala> val test = new Container(listtest)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Array[Some[Any]]]
 required: Iterable[Iterable[Option[Any]]]
       val test = new Container(listtest)
                                ^

scala> val test = new Container(List(row1,row2))
test: Container= Container@600a08
```

How come defining the Container the second way works, but the first one doesn't? Aren't the types the same?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is no bug. `Array` is not covariant. B being a subtype of B does not make  Array[B]  a subtype of Array[A]. This is contrary to java, where B[] is a subtype of A[], which is unsound:

```
A[] b = new B[1];
b[0] = new (A);
-> ArrayStoreException
```

So your Array[Some[Any]] is not an Array[Option[Any]]. You must make sure you have an Array[Option], which you may do with

```
val row2 = Array[Option[Any]](Some(test2), Some(12345))
```

You can also use a type abscription on one of the item:

```
val row2 = Array(Some(test2): Option[String], Some(12345))
```

Or if you know your values are non-null,

```
val row2 = Array(Option(test2), Option(12345))
```

(It's enough to do that on one of the value)

`List`, on the other hand is covariant, which is why it works.

It is actually unfortunate that the more precise type `Some` is inferred, it is quite uncommon that you want the type of something to be known as `Some` (or `None`) rather than `Option`.

**Edit** Sorry, looks like I completely missed the point, about why there are different. `Array` is not covariant, but Iterable is. So it would seems that `Array[B]` while not being an `Array[A]`, should be an `Iterable[A]`, then everything should work. It would be so if Array was a subtype of Iterable. It is not, it comes with the JVM, cannot be made to extend `Iterable`. What there is is an implicit conversion to `WrappedArray`, which is an `Iterable`.

When you write `val l = List(row1, row2)`, it has no reason to apply this conversion. It types list as precisely as it can. Then the fact that List is covariant (a List[B] is a List[A] if B is an A) will not kick in when we have not B is an A, but B has an implicit conversion to A.

On the other hand, when you write val l: List[Iterable[A]] = List(x,y) then the List(...) function expects Iterable[A] arguments, and at this point it looks for implicit conversions.

Still not a bug, but trickier than I thought. Maybe you could do a

```
class Container[T <% Iterable[Option[Any]]](val rows: Iterable[T])
```

Comment: You know, I was wondering if I was going mad. Then you added your edit. Array is not an Iterable, and implicit conversions have problems when you're applying them to type parameter like that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573414/how-to-convert-java-map-to-scala-map-of-type-linkedhashmapstring-arrayliststrin)

Comment: Well I have to thank comments from Franza and Alexey for that. I first had been way too fast, and did not pause to think after I spotted Array[Some...].

Answer (score 4):

I tried your code and there was the same exception. Then I replaced

```
scala> val listtest = List(row1, row2)
```

on

```
scala>  val listtest: Iterable[Iterable[Option[Any]]] = List(row1, row2)
listtest: Iterable[Iterable[Option[Any]]] = List(WrappedArray(Some(test), Some(1234)), WrappedArray(Some(test2), Some(12345)))
```

and it worked fine:

```
scala> val test = new Container(listtest)
test: Container = Container@a75974
```

Answer (score 3):

In first case, the type of `listtest` is inferred from its definition: `List[Array[Some[Any]]]`. @didierd explains why this is not a suitable type for the argument of `Container` constructor.

In second case, the type argument of `List(row1,row2)` is inferred from the fact it's used as the constructor argument.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is with implicit conversions. Scala does not try to apply implicit conversions for type parameters for 'contained types'.

Array is a not an Iterable, so if you were to use

```
val row1 = List(Some("test2"), Some(12345))
```

this works. But you're using Array, so it should try to find an implicit conversion for Array -> Iterable (which does exist), but it does not try. I'll try and find a better reference for this, but in the meantime, you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573414/how-to-convert-java-map-to-scala-map-of-type-linkedhashmapstring-arrayliststrin).

If you explicitly specify as an Iterable the type of row, then this works, because the type inferencing works.

```
val row1: Iterable[Option[Any]] = Array(Some("test2"), Some(1234))
```