# How to build an Scala immutable map from a mutable Java map?

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

The below class causes the compiler error :

```
value toMap is not a member of 
 java.util.Map[java.lang.String,java.util.List[com.recommendations.TestObject]]


class ProcessData(var distanceMap : java.util.Map[java.lang.String , java.util.List[TestObject]]) {

    def apply = {

      val m2: Map[String, Any] = distanceMap.toMap

    }

}
```

This line causes the error :

```
val m2: Map[String, Any] = distanceMap.toMap
```

Is the error because the value of Map distanceMap is an mutable java.util.List , hence these values need also be immutable ?

How can I build a Scala immutable map from the mutable distanceMap above ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert java Map to scala Map of type LinkedHashMap\[String,ArrayList\[String\]\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573414/how-to-convert-java-map-to-scala-map-of-type-linkedhashmapstring-arrayliststri)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val m = new java.util.HashMap[String, Object]()
m.put("Foo", java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)
m.put("Bar", java.lang.Integer.valueOf(1))

val m2: Map[String, Any] = m.toMap
println(m2);
```

Comment: your code does not compile, java.util.Map is an interface, not a concrete class so cannot instantiate. .toMap method is not a member of java.util.Map

Comment: I'm receiving a compiler error for above code : "Multiple markers at this line
 - value toMap is not a member of java.util.HashMap[String,java.lang.Object]
 - Cannot prove that Char <:< (T, U).
 - Implicit conversions found: m => augmentString(m)
 - not enough arguments for method toMap: (implicit ev: <:<[Char,(T, 
  U)])scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]. Unspecified value parameter ev."

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing the JavaConversions import.  Your code will compile with:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
class ProcessData(var distanceMap : java.util.Map[java.lang.String , java.util.List[TestObject]]) {
    def apply = {
      val m2: Map[String, Any] = distanceMap.toMap
    }
}
```