# How can I convert a Java map of maps for use in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-java-interop

I working on a Scala program that calls a function from a Java library, processes the results, and spits out a CSV.

The Java function in question looks like this:

```
    Map<String, Map<String, AtomicLong>> getData();
```

The Scala:

```
    import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
    def analysisAndCsvStuff(data: Map[String, Map[String, AtomicLong]]): Unit { ... }
```

The error:

```
    type mismatch;
    found:java.util.Map[java...String,java...Map[java...String,java...AtomicLong]]
    required: scala...Map[String,scala...Map[String,java...AtomicLong]]
```

(The path names were ruining the formatting.)

I'm guessing that the JavaConversions can successfully convert the outer java...Map but not the inner java...Map. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573414/how-to-convert-java-map-to-scala-map-of-type-linkedhashmapstring-arrayliststri) but I am unsure of how to go about writing an "explicit implicit conversion".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: the [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301947/what-is-the-difference-between-javaconverters-and-javaconversions-in-scala) is to use `JavaConverters` and the `.asScala` method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val myScalaMap = myJavaMap.asScala.mapValues(_.asScala)
```

Note that you will get mutable maps out of this. You can always use `.asScala.toMap` if you want immutable ones.

---

*The original answer with `JavaConversions`*:

The short answer is: call `.mapValues` on the outer map to convert the inner map:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
val myScalaMap = myJavaMap.mapValues(_.toMap)
```

`.mapValues` forces the conversion or the outer map to a scala `Map` and `.toMap` forces the conversion of the inner map to a scala (*immutable*) map. The immutable part isn't strictly necessary, but anyways...

This is very similar to [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920087/738138). Short example:

```
scala> val a: java.util.Map[String, java.util.Map[String, String]] = new java.util.HashMap[String, java.util.Map[String, String]]
a: java.util.Map[String,java.util.Map[String,String]] = {}


scala> import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

scala> val myScalaMap = a.mapValues(_.toMap)
myScalaMap: scala.collection.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Map()
```

Comment: Huzzah! Works perfectly. Thanks for the quick and succinct response!

Comment: @SamDaniel np :). See my update, although both versions are perfectly valid.

Comment: I think the JavaConverters version.  I commented on the linked answer that people strongly recommend using asScala.

Comment: @som-snytt thanks, I wasn't sure about that. Then it is surprising `JavaConversions` isn't deprecated in 2.11.

Answer (score 2):

> I am unsure of how to go about writing an "explicit implicit conversion"

Using `JavaConverters` of course, that phrase suggests a custom implicit.

Here is the back and forth:

```
scala> import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

scala> import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong

scala> val m = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> new AtomicLong(7L)))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong]] = Map(a -> Map(b -> 7))

scala> val j = m mapValues (_.asJava) asJava
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
j: java.util.Map[String,java.util.Map[String,java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong]] = {a={b=7}}

scala> implicit class mapmap[A,B,C](val v:
     | java.util.Map[A,java.util.Map[B,C]]) extends AnyVal {
     | def asMapMap: Map[A,Map[B,C]] =
     | v.asScala.toMap.mapValues(_.asScala.toMap)
     | }
defined class mapmap

scala> j.asMapMap
res0: Map[String,Map[String,java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong]] = Map(a -> Map(b -> 7))
```

Comment: Thanks! Scala's "implicit" seemed like voodoo to me at first, a Scala n00b and someone trained in the arts of ML's type system. But I'm pretty sure I understand how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are 2 versions of `Maps` and other major collections in scala, mutable and immutable. The default of use is immutable version, and you can access mutable version through  `scala.collection.mutable` package.

Because of the mutability of java Collections, converting java Collections to scala mutable  Collections is pretty much easier than converting to scala immutable Collections. `JavaConversions` is unable to  convert java Collections to scala immutable Collections.

Furthermore, `JavaCollections` cannot convert your inner collections to scala types.

I suggest you to convert your java Map as a scala data structure as follows.

```
val javaMap:java.util.HashMap[String,java.util.Map[String,Int]] = new java.util.HashMap()

val scalaMap:Map[String,Map[String,Int]] = javaMap.toMap.map { case (k,v) => k -> v.toMap}
```

The `.tomap` method is defined in `scala.collection.mutable.Map` which converts `mutable Map` to `immutable Map`. and `JavaConversions` converts `java.util.Map` to scala immutable `Map`

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use [scalaj-collection](https://github.com/jozic/scalaj) library i wrote specifically for this purpose

```
import com.daodecode.scalaj.collection._

analysisAndCsvStuff(getData.deepAsScala)
```

that's it. It will convert all nested java collections and primitive types to scala versions. You can also convert directly to immutable data structures using `deepAsScalaImmutable` (with some copying overhead of course)